# What is the proper way to down-cast a parent class property to call a child-specific method?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I've run into this problem a few times and the fact that I can't find an answer makes me think I'm doing something weird at a fundamental level, but here goes:

I have an abstract class that contains an interface (or abstract class) property that defines all of the common methods that any child would need:

```
interface IFoo
{
    ...
}

abstract class Parent
{
    IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a child class that implements that abstract class, and in its constructor, it sets that interface property to its own implementation:

```
class Child : Parent
{
    Child()
    {
       Foo = new ChildFoo();
    }
}

class ChildFoo : IFoo
{
    SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I need to call SomeMethod() in Child, I need to downcast Foo to ChildFoo first. Should I just add a getter property in Child that just returns Foo as ChildFoo? Or am I doing something wrong at a fundamental level?

Edit:

I apologize for the edit and for unaccepting the answer (which may actually still stand), but I feel like I should have been more explicit because I'm still a bit lost.

Parent and Child are actually OData controllers and IFoo is a service layer interface that defines basic CRUD methods.

There are many child OData controllers, all of which contain endpoints for the CRUD methods defined by IFoo. However, some children also have custom function endpoints that call entity-specific methods that are not defined in IFoo.

I was hoping to avoid a lot of redundant Controller code by having all of the common child endpoints call generic methods in the Parent controller using the IFoo property. The problem is that I can't call the entity-specific methods in the Child controller without casting IFoo to ChildFoo().

I'm starting to think I should just remove the Parent controller altogether and add a helper class that contains methods with IFoo parameters.

Apologies if I'm just repeating myself..

Thanks

Comment: Why not make `SomeMethod` a member of the `IFoo` interface?

Comment: Is `SomeMethod` defined in `IFoo`?

Comment: @JonathonChase SomeMethod only applies to ChildFoo.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something wrong at a fundamental level.  You set `Foo` to be a `ChildFoo` in the constructor, but you expose a property getter in which you let *anyone* set it to be *any* `IFoo` instance.

Either you need to ensure that no one can ever set that property to anything other than what your constructor has set it to (by making it read only), at which point you can safely ensure that it'll always be a `ChildFoo` (and in such a case you should simply store it in a field of that type, and have the read only property return it, rather than casting it whenever you use it).  Or, if it needs to be settable externally, then `IFoo` apparently needs that method, because you need any `IFoo` instance to be able to perform that operation.

Answer (score 1):

One fundamental problem is if you have an `IFoo` and you cast it as a specific class that implements `IFoo`, like `ChildFoo`.

The point of an interface such as `IFoo` is so that other code deals with the interface, not any concrete types that implement it. If code elsewhere "knows" that an `IFoo` is really a `ChildFoo`, then `IFoo` has lost its reason to exist.

- If `ChildFoo` is the only class that implements `IFoo`, then you don't need `IFoo`. (Except perhaps for unit testing, but that still won't work if you're casting the interface to a concrete type.)
- If other classes implement `IFoo`, then how do you know that a given `IFoo` is a `ChildFoo` and not some other class that implements `IFoo`?
- Even if `ChildFoo` is the only class that implements `IFoo` now, what if other classes implement `IFoo` later?

When we cast an interface to something that implements it, we're taking it upon ourselves to keep track of all of those details, which is risky and can result in runtime errors.

But we're also losing one of the intended benefits of interfaces, which is that our code depends only on the interface, not any particular implementation.